# Convert a float to two int in c/++

Tags: c++, casting

***NOT A DUPLICATE***: the duplicated mentioned above, returns the decimal part into a float, and not a int

Given I have a float `1.495` How can I convert it into, `1` and `495` given two `int` variables `r` and `d`. Where:

```
int r == 1;
int d == 495;
```

I can get the first one using

```
int r = (int)(1.495f-1l);
```

But im not sure on how to cast or get the `d` value.

*Note I am not sure of the range of decimal part, the decimal part could be `.49` or `.495` or `.4959`*

*In the case of the value being `.0495` or `.00495` I am OK with the value being returned to be 495, I didn't think of this originally.*

Thanks

Comment: int d = (int)((1.500f-r)*1000);

Comment: use a regex.. `(\d+)\.(\d+)`

Comment: x13n I cant do * 1000, as the decimal value might be `500102`

Comment: If undestand right, you want to separate decimal and integral part. Do you?

Comment: Yes @StefanoSanfilippo but into two ints `r` and `d`

Comment: Not a duplicated, The `modf` function returns the decimal part in a float

Comment: As a(n IEEE754) `double`, `1.495` is actually `1.49500000000000010658141036401502788066864013671875`, and as a single-precision `float`, it's `1.49500000476837158203125`. How would you determine that for the fractional part you want `495` and not `49500000476837158203125`? Also, what about `1.0495`?

Comment: @DanielFischer getting 49500000476837158203125 is actually OK from what I am after, and I know that int casting will lose some of the percission. However you make a good point, what about `0495`. From my perspective I am OK with it being `495` however that is out of my questions scope.

Comment: @Monolo I am not sure exactly what you mean by "but that the problem it is not sufficiently specified". I have clearly mentioned given a float 1.495 I want 1 and 495 in two integer variables.

Comment: Yes, but you use a single double value as your example, and as @DanielFischer has demonstrated, this is not even a precise value. Hence, we need a mathematical explanation of what you are looking for, that will take into account the inherent limitations of the IEEE floating point format (for instance that in the normal case you don't have a one-to-one translation from the base 2 format of the double to the base 10 format that you want). When you don't have a one-to-one translation, the problem is underspecified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
float f = 1.5;
int r = f;
int d = (f-r)*1000;
```

**Update:**

Just to be clear, while this answered the poster's question as originally phrased, it does not solve the problem as its given now.

Comment: d depends on the floating points current range. It is subject to change any time you cannot know what with to multiply. It could be 1.500 or 1.500000 or 1.5000000

Comment: Thanks but that does not help if the range is greater than `1000`

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Those numbers are all the same as floating point. Unless it's a string.

Comment: Yes they are the same and they are different in precision. For the next few lines, it can change to 1.499999999.

Comment: But unless you're storing them as strings, the computer is not going to be able to tell them apart. If this is a string manipulation question then you should probably make that clearer.

Comment: Its not a string manipulation question. I didn't mention strings anywhere

Comment: Throwing in a suggestion, maybe the modulus operator could be used to find the length of the decimal

Comment: 1.5 and 1.500 is same but when you have 1(int)  and 5000(int) what do you get when you do inversely? Divide by 1000 again? or 100?

Comment: @JimHurley That only makes sense if you're trying to tell the difference between something like 1.5 and 1.55 where the one has 1 digit of the decimal point and the other has two. There is no difference between 1.5 and 1.50 though unless they're strings.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify the question by showing two examples in the form `float f1 = ???` and `float f2 = ???` and what you expect them to be converted to. If `f1` and `f2` are something like `1.5` and `1.500` and you're expecting different results, that's never going to happen.

Comment: I understand what you're asking now, but that is different from your original question. Under these conditions 1.500 would return 1 and 5, not 1 and 500. Also, you should be aware that 1.5 and 1.00005 would both return 1 and 5.